# Multiple routers in Express Node.js

Tags: express, routes

How can I  display my data from mongoDB that have collections?
When I want to display they apart, its word but not when I try to reach them all together.
For example:

My index.js:

```
app.use('/menu', menuController);
```

My menuController.js:

```
router.use('/morning', morningController);
router.use('/starters', startersController);
router.use('/sandwiches', sandwichesController);
router.use('/toasts', toastsController);
router.use('/kidsMeal', kidsMealController);
router.use('/salats', salatsController);
router.use('/italianCuisine', italianCuisineController);
router.use('/mains', mainsController);
router.use('/stirFried', stirFriedController);
router.use('/desserts', dessertsController);
router.use('/softDrinks', softDrinksController);
router.use('/refreshing', refreshingController);
router.use('/hotBeverages', hotBeveragesController);
router.use('/warming', warmingController);
router.use('/various', variousController);
```

when I reach " http://localhost:2121/menu/morning"
I'm seeing my data in JSON from my Database (even when in get '/variousController').
But when I trying to get ' http://localhost:2121/menu', I'm getting an arrow ' Cannot GET /menu'.
What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> < But when I trying to get ' http://localhost:2121/menu', I'm getting an arrow ' Cannot GET /menu'. What I'm doing wrong?

You don't have any router in your router for "/" so the URL `/menu` all by itself has no route handler.

If you want `/menu` to have a handler, then define one:

```
router.get('/', someHandler);    // to serve /menu
```

FYI, is there a reason you're using `router.use()` instead of an http-verb-specific variety such as `router.get()` for your endpoint handlers?  `router.use()` matches all verbs including GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS, etc... which is generally not what you want for an endpoint handler.  An endpoint handler should only match the verb it is designed for.